# Find the distance between 2 coords in pandas with haversine error

Tags: python, pandas, distance, haversine

I want to find the distance between 2 coords with Haversine in pandas, but it gives me the error:
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

```
my df:
   latitude    longitude    buc_lat    buc_long
0  46.161411   27.662575    44.433     26.1024
1  44.420262   26.126688    44.433     26.1024
2  44.413853   26.096157    44.433     26.1024
```

my code:

```
import numpy as np

def haversine_vectorize(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):

    newlon = lon2 - lon1
    newlat = lat2 - lat1

    haver_formula = np.sin(newlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(newlon/2.0)**2

    dist = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(haver_formula ))
    km = 6367 * dist #6367 for distance in KM for miles use 3958
    return km
```

Comment: Please share a [mcve] with data which is easily usable.

Comment: All the `lat` and `long` in `haversine_vectorize()` must be in radians. Do it by multiplying with `np.pi/180`.

Answer (score 0):

You fails to use correct units when dealing with computation concerning `lat` and `long` in the relevant formulas. Here are the runnable code, step by step.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_str = """index   latitude    longitude    buc_lat    buc_long
0  46.161411   27.662575    44.433     26.1024
1  44.420262   26.126688    44.433     26.1024
2  44.413853   26.096157    44.433     26.1024"""

df3 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), sep='\s+', index_col='index')
```

At this step, the dataframe `df3` is

```
        latitude  longitude  buc_lat  buc_long
index                                                      
0      46.161411  27.662575   44.433   26.1024
1      44.420262  26.126688   44.433   26.1024
2      44.413853  26.096157   44.433   26.1024
```

Your distance function should look like this.

```
def haversine_vectorize(row):
    rho = np.pi/180
    # convert all values to radians
    lon1=row.longitude*rho
    lat1=row.latitude*rho
    lon2=row.buc_long*rho
    lat2=row.buc_lat*rho

    newlon = lon2 - lon1
    newlat = lat2 - lat1

    haver_formula = np.sin(newlat/2.0)**2 + np.cos(lat1) * np.cos(lat2) * np.sin(newlon/2.0)**2

    dist = 2 * np.arcsin(np.sqrt(haver_formula ))
    # use appropriate value for radius of the earth (this is crude!)
    km = 6367 * dist #6367 for distance in KM for miles use 3958
    print(" Distance {} km:".format(km))
    return km
```

To compute and get the distances, do this.

```
ans = df3.apply(haversine_vectorize, axis=1)
```

Create a new column in the dataframe `df3` to keep the distances just obtained.

```
df3["distance_km"] = ans
```

Finally, you will get the dataframe as

```
        latitude  longitude  buc_lat  buc_long  distance_km
index                                                      
0      46.161411  27.662575   44.433   26.1024   227.506591
1      44.420262  26.126688   44.433   26.1024     2.391419
2      44.413853  26.096157   44.433   26.1024     2.184640
```